# How to get the Virtual IP Address associated with a Azure App Service via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to do an IP changeover and I'm looking to get the Virtual IP of all our app service instances.

So far I've put together the following powershell script:

```
$apps = Get-AzureRmWebApp 
Foreach($app in $apps) 
{ 
  Write-Output "$($app.Name)|$($app.OutboundIpAddresses)"

  ($app | Get-AzureDeployment -Slot Production).VirtualIPs[0].Address

  break;
}
```

But I'm stuck at the Get-AzureDeployment step - I think there should be a RM version of this, but I can't find it.

Related GitHub issue - this indicates it does exist: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1648

I'm trying to get to the Virtual Ip Address as per the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You are looking for [Get-AzureRmWebAppSlot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/get-azurermwebappslot?view=azurermps-6.8.1)?

Comment: I'm not sure, will try it out :)

Comment: You want to get the `OutboundIpAddresses` of the web app slot?

Comment: No, I want to get the Virtual IP assigned to the App Service instance

Comment: Please see the screenshot added above

Comment: Added an additional screenshot url - I think there is a difference between the virtual and outbound ips - the one only has a single ip

Comment: Seems to be the first part of the outbound ips.

Comment: Yeah it does match in many cases.. I'm not sure if it does for all .. My end goal is to compare the 2 across all 50 or so app services

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS`, you could use the command below.

```
$slot = Get-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -Name "<yourwebappname>" -Slot "<yourslotname>" 
($slot.OutboundIpAddresses -split ",")[0]
```

[image]

Your complete command should be:

```
    $apps = Get-AzureRmWebApp 
    Foreach($app in $apps) 
    { 
      Write-Output "$($app.Name)|$($app.OutboundIpAddresses)"

      $slot = Get-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $app.ResourceGroup -Name $app.Name -Slot "<yourslotname>" 
      ($slot.OutboundIpAddresses -split ",")[0]

      break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Joy-Wang - but I'm not convinced it is 100% the correct answer, it feels like it is relying on the co-incidence that the first outbound ip seems to match the virtual ip

Comment: @user230910 Agree with you. But I could not find the `VIRTUAL IP ADDRESS` in the azure resource explorer, so strange.

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that the virtual ip is not 100% the first ip, I have 5 (out of 50) app services where it is different, I eventually ended up doing it by hand.